# Why is this question appearing in review but doesnt exist on Stackoverflow?

Tags: bug, review

I went to review some close questions.

The first question I was given for my filter was

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3477098

I clicked on the title to view the full question and edit it ( I wanted to remove one of the tags), but the link went to a page not found page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934758/gray-screen-when-trying-to-configure-a-new-database-or-create-a-new-flow

Why am I being asked to review a question that seems to have already been removed?

Comment: The question was deleted about a week ago. It was either an audit or a review that started before it was deleted (but didn't get cleared).

Comment: @JeffMercado surely the bug is that it should get cleared?

Comment: @JeffMercado it was an audit, I just tried to close it via the review page

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards that question seems to suggest my missing question was there as a 'tester' to make sure I was paying attention, jeffMercado suggests its a bug, do we know which it is?

Comment: @psubsee2003 in that case could the close page tell me its an Audit?

Comment: Click on the review link again. It was an audit... it says so now.

Comment: @TobyAllen the point is that it is an audit to test you (not a bug).  As soon as you complete the review, it will tell you that it was an audit and whether you passed or failed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I understand that, but I didnt complete the review I click on the question link and it looked like a bug, I'm just suggesting it tells you its an audit when you click on the question also.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the point of the audit @Toby?

Comment: It might reduce the number of people like me who think its a bug!

Comment: @TobyAllen honestly, if the users who thought it was a bug searched meta first, they would find one the dups we linked, or now they will find your post which will point them back to the original.